# how to reinstall pam and configure pam

Tags: gnome, gdm, pam

I manually installed linux-pam-1.30, configure with prefix=/usr, and removed file in /etc/pam.d/, now start ubuntu will stop at login process, because gdm will auto login, but pam will failed to auth gdm, I have checked log file. how to reinstall default pam and reconfigure pam?
ps my ubuntu was ubuntu16.04 gnome version

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason was I removed file in /etc/pam.d, restore those files system resumed.

Comment: what file did you remove and how did you restore it?